# Наложение одного элемента на другой в HTML-письме

Tags: html, css, вёрстка-email

Можно ли наложить один элемент на другой в HTML-письме (!) следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

???

Чтобы это работало хотя бы в современных почтовых агентах типа Gmail, Apple Mail 10 и т.д.

С прискорбием узнала, что `position` не работает [практически нигде](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/positioning-display/position/).

Или в этом случае проще всё безжалостно делать картинками?

Comment: Самый быстрый вариант (он же костыль) это поиграться margin.

Comment: Отрицательный margin не работает, к сожалению. Но кажется, я нашла решение с помощью табличной верстки.

Comment: Всё верно, email-письма нужно верстать таблицами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Классический подход в верстке писем - таблицами.
Здесь видна таблица из трех столбцов, в первом строки объединены, второй и третий - по три строки.

Если идет наложение одной картинки на другую, то здесь нужно нарезать 5 частей (картинок) и две прозрачные какртнки-распорки для ячеек с1 и с3 и вставить их в соответствующие ячейки.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]